# Error in MultipartEntity submission while ant build

Tags: ant, httpclient

I am trying to build a executable jar application for ODK client to
download the files from mobile to local system.

I am trying to send  HTTP post request with the zip files as a
multipart entity. The execution of jar file give the following error.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/ContentBody

if I am running a standalone application, the HTTP post request works
fine. But an ant build of a swing class calling the HTTP post request
gives the error. I tried to include the required jars too.

Does anyone has encountered something similar.

regards

Comment: Which JARs are you including in your Ant classpath?

Comment: I have included apache-mime4j-0.5.jar, httpmime-4.0.1.jar, httpclient-4.1.2.jar, httpcore-4.1.2.jar, org.apache.commons.io.jar

Comment: I did play with other jars too...The following link has all the collections of jar...I tried to search for the jar in the error message but no luck..  https://github.com/Topol/formhubloader/tree/master/koboproc/kobo.postproc/lib

Answer (score 1):

Where did you put all these referenced jars? They have to be under folder named "libs" in your project. No other places.